Upgrading from Magento 2.3.7-pt to Magento 2.4.0
I've been trying to upgrade my magento version from 2.3.7-p2 to 2.4.0
I've double checked all system requirements and everything is good.
When I run composer update I get this error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.9
- Conclusion: remove gene/module-braintree 4.0.8
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.8
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.7
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.6
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.5
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.4
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.2
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
- Conclusion: don't install gene/module-braintree 4.0.1
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires paypal/module-braintree 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree[4.1.0].
- paypal/module-braintree 4.1.0 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.1.0].
- paypal/module-braintree 4.1.0 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.1.0].
- paypal/module-braintree-core 4.1.0 conflicts with gene/module-braintree[4.0.0].
- paypal/module-braintree-core 4.1.0 conflicts with gene/module-braintree[4.0.0].
- Installation request for gene/module-braintree ^4.0 -> satisfiable by gene/module-braintree[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9].
I've tried to uninstall this module then tried running composer update but when I do that I get an out of memory error, even when running composer update with unlimited memory.
After that I tried upgrading composer to v2, but was unsuccessful and received this error:
Problem 1
- laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4] require composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.6.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4].
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
I'm unsure what to do at this point. I've never ran into these issues when upgrading my magento store

@Christian
Hey,
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update

Execute above command and then execute composer update.
Thank You!
